# Python:How to print object key in a dictionary properly?

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a Graph class and a Vertex class, defined as below

Graph.py

```
class Graph:

def __init__(self):
    self.adjacencyList = {}

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.adjacencyList)

def addVetex(self,key,value):
    if Vertex(key,value) not in self.adjacencyList:
        self.adjacencyList[Vertex(key,value)] = []
```

Vertex.py

```
class Vertex:
def __init__(self,key,value):
    self.key = key
    self.value = value

def __str__(self):
    return "Key: ",str(self.key)," Value: ",str(self,value)

def __hash__(self):
    return self.key
```

if I do this:

```
G = Graph()
G.addVetex(1,None)
G.addVetex(2,None)
G.addVetex(1,3)
print G
```

It print out `{<Vertex.Vertex instance at 0x110295b90>: [], <Vertex.Vertex instance at 0x110295bd8>: []}` But I am expecting something like `{"Key:1 Value:None":[]...}`

My question is what I am doing wrong? When a diction got print out, why it does not try to call the **str** function of its keys/values?

Thanks.

Comment: You set a `Vertex` object as your key: `self.adjacencyList[Vertex(key,value)] = []`, hence the key is the object itself and not `1` or `2`, ...

Comment: Yeah I know that, is there any way I can print it out properly?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. Well, I cannot answer that, but I think its a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the method you want to implement to get the string you want with your current code is `Vertex.__repr__`, which is what the python dictionary uses to get string representations of keys.

Here's a [related stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) answer that sheds some light on the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__`

Answer (score 1):

Joe's answer is correct, here is the tested version of the code:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Key: "+str(self.key)+" Value: "+str(self.value)
```

to be implemented in `Vertex`. Also important is that a string is given back, not a tuple as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.  Note the addition of the **repr** method (and a little cleanup of the **str** method).

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self,key,value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "{Key: "+str(self.key)+" Value: "+str(self.value)+"}"

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.key

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

You might consider subclassing a dict, though, for your vertex class.  You get all the benefits of a dict but can add methods to suit your needs.  The simplest version of this would look like:

```
class Vertex(dict):
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do smth like:

```
class Graph(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join("Key: " + str(i.key) + " Value: " + str(i.value) for i in self.adjacencyList)
```